# Hide a div but ONLY if it is within another specific div class

Tags: html, css

I have a div and I don't want another div to show IF it held within.

My question is, how do I make

```
<div class="xp-row xp-first-row">

  <div class="social-buttons">
      Some Content Here
  </div>

</div>
```

But if the div called "social-buttons" is standalone then it will not be hidden...

I was thinking something like this would work:

```
.xp-row xp-first-row .social-buttons{
  visibility:none
}
```

But I couldn't get that to work - any ideas?

Thanks for all help

Comment: Your outer element has two classes, you need to join those with a dot in your selector - and not have a _space_ between them, because that would be the general descendant combinator. `.xp-row.xp-first-row .social-buttons`

Comment: With `.xp-row xp-first-row`, you’d be looking for an element with the _tag name_ `xp-first-row`, that is a _descendant_ of an element with the class `xp-row`.

Answer (score 1):

Rule `.xp-row.xp-first-row` should be declared without spaces as it is placed within one `div`:

```
.xp-row.xp-first-row .social-buttons {
    visibility: hidden;  
}
```

An example:

```css
.xp-row.xp-first-row .social-buttons{
  visibility: hidden;  
}
```

```html
<div class="xp-row xp-first-row">
    <div class="social-buttons">
        Some Content Here
    </div>
  </div>
```